# Python Subprocess.run standard out

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have the following function that executes as expected.

```
def get_files(paths):
    for path in paths:
        file_name = parse_path(path)
        csv_command = "curl -b ./cookie {} > ./tmp/{}".format(path, file_name)
        subprocess.run([csv_command], shell=True)
    print("success")
```

My issue here is that I am also capturing standardout from the subprocess. How do I modify the function to ignore the standard out of the subprocess. I will be logging using a logger and need to make sure that logging will still occur to STDout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a handle to the DEVNULL directory for the standard output. (which can be accessed using subprocess.DEVNULL)

This should suppress output from your function

```py
subprocess.run([csv_command], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

You can see some more options by reading this page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL

Answer (score 0):

Just close the file-descriptor:

```
process.stdout.close()
```

Where `process` is the process which you desire to not read from.